# Where is the (meta) .proto file which describes .desc files?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Where is the (meta) .proto file which describes .desc files?

I make .desc files with:

```
protoc --descriptor_set_out=foo.desc --include_imports foo.proto
```

Am I correct in believing that the .desc files are in protobuf format?

If so, where can I get the .proto file which describes their format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format is `FileDescriptorSet` as defined in `descriptor.proto`:

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

`descriptor.proto` is typically installed to `/usr/include/descriptor.proto` or `/usr/local/include/descriptor.proto` on Unix systems.  `descriptor.pb.h` is installed with the protobuf headers and `descriptor.pb.cc` is compiled into the protobuf library, so you don't have to generate them yourself if you are using C++.  Similarly, in Java, the `com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos` class is compiled into the base library.

Comment: It got moved to GitHub here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

Answer (score 2):

If you install protocol buffers, the definition is in

```
   <PB install directory>/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

Some/Most of the Instalation processes (e.g. Java) will "Generate" pb classes from this definition.

As keton said it is also available at

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, it should be in the reference documentation, here:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor.pb#FileDescriptorSet