# Having problems using the python code generated from the google protocol buffer

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, importerror, gtfs

I am getting the following error when I try to run gtfs_realtime_pb2.py (the python code generated from running the gtfs-realtime.proto through google's protocol buffer):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor
ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

This is a link to the specific code I am having trouble with:
https://github.com/mattwigway/gtfsrdb

And the link to installing google's protocol buffer:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

I am pretty certain I have install the buffer correctly, so why is it throwing up that it can't find this module?

Comment: I am not familiar with python PB. But with Java PB, there is a separate java install step where java classes are generated from the descriptor.proto. It sounds like there it is the descriptor classes that are missing from your install.

Comment: My understanding of how the protocol buffer works was that you gave it a .proto file which sets out how the message is structured, then the buffer generates a a code file which holds all of the message classes in your chosen language.

Comment: If you run the google supplied gtfs-realtime.proto file into the protocol buffer it generates the gtfs-realtime.py which holds the classes. Are you saying that there is also something else that is generated in this process which python calls on to interpret the realtime feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included in protocol buffer is **descriptor.proto**; python code for this proto should of been generated as part of the install process.

The protocol buffer you are using uses descriptor.proto so the directory where it resides needs to be included via the --proto_path= parameter (see [Importing "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto" in java protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069295/importing-google-protobuf-descriptor-proto-in-java-protocol-buffers/20082776#20082776)

For window systems, the install directory will be where you placed it; for *nix it will probably be [answer taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636887/where-is-the-meta-proto-file-which-describes-desc-files/18645329#18645329)

```
    /usr/include/descriptor.proto 
or 
    /usr/local/include/descriptor.proto
```

i.e. for java you would do something like

```
protoc addressbookSD.proto --java_out=./ --proto_path=./ --proto_path=<protobuf-install-directory>/src
```

where **<protobuf-install-directory>** is the protocol buffers install directory. The key point is descriptor.proto is in

```
<protobuf-install-directory>\src\google\protobuf
```